# XML-RPC.NET Mapping Unknown Type

Tags: c#, xml, struct, xml-rpc, xml-rpc.net

I'm using XML-RPC.NET library to map responses from Wordpress' APIs. However Im getting the following issue regarding the mapping of an article image.

If the response contains an image it will return a struct like so

```
<member>
  <name>post_thumbnail</name>
  <value>
    <struct>
        ...
    </struct>
  </value>
</member>
```

Which I can then map to my struct in c#

```
public struct PostThumbnail
{
    //Thumbnail properties
}
```

If there is no image then I get an empty array in the response instead of a struct

```
<member>
  <name>post_thumbnail</name>
  <value>
    <array>
      <data>
      </data>
    </array>
  </value>
</member>
```

This doesnt map and throws the following error

**CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcTypeMismatchException**
response contains array value where struct expected [response : array mapped to type Post[] : element 0 : struct mapped to type Post : member post_thumbnail mapped to type PostThumbnail]

Is there a way I can ignore this mapping if the wrong type has been returned?